# Python range() with negative strides

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way of using the `range()` function with stride -1?

E.g. using `range(10, -10)` instead of the square-bracketed values below?

I.e the following line:

```
for y in range(10,-10)
```

Instead of

```
for y in [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10]:
```

Obviously one could do this with another kind of loop more elegantly but the `range()` example would work much better for what I want.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can specify the stride (including a negative stride) as the third argument, so

```
range(10,-11,-1)
```

gives

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

In general, it doesn't cost anything to try. You can simply type this into the interpreter and see what it does.

This is all [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) as:

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

but mostly I'd like to encourage you to play around and see what happens. As you can see, your intuition was spot on.

Comment: You're probably right, it's a weakness. Perhaps positive encouragment would be better ...

Comment: I think the comment is fair. I did try it in the interpreter, but I didn't put in strides.

Comment: I think this comment is completely fair - to mention the ``range()`` builtin but not bother to read the docs was pointless. What he wanted was right there.

Comment: My original answer was less constructive though, so props to @bernie for nudging me to improve it.

Comment: Exact thing I wanted.
Thank you very much, only thing I was missing was step with -1

Answer (score 11):

Yes, by defining a step:

```
for i in range(10, -11, -1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other good answers, there is an alternative:

```
for y in reversed(range(-10, 11)):
```

See the documentation for [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).

Answer (score 6):

You may notice that the range function works only in ascending order without the third parameter. If you use it without the third parameter in the range block, it will not work.

```
for i in range(10,-11)
```

The above loop will not work.
For the above loop to work, you have to use the third parameter as a negative number.

```
for i in range(10,-11,-1)
```

(Also note that you need to have the "stop" parameter at the next number in the negative sequence, -11, from what you wanted, -10, just like in a standard, ascending range.).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, however you'll need to specify that you want to step backwards by setting the step argument to -1.

Use:

`for y in range(10, -10, -1)`

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't print -10... it goes from 10 to -9.

Answer (score 2):

For your case using  `range(10,-10,-1)`
will be helpful. The first argument refers to the first step, the second one refers to the last step, and the third argument refers to the size of that step.
When your range is ascending, you do not need to specify the steps if you need all numbers between, `range(-10,10)` or `range(-10,-5)`.

But when your range is descending, you need to specify the step size as -1, `range(10,-10,-1)` or any other larger steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer create list in range:

```
numbers = list(range(-10, 10))
```

Comment: Smart alternative!

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, these 3 are the best efficient and relevant to answer approaches I believe:

```
first = list(x for x in range(10, -11, -1))

second = list(range(-10, 11))

third = [x for x in reversed(range(-10, 11))]
```

Alternatively, NumPy would be more efficient as it creates an array as below, which is much faster than creating and writing items to the list in python. You can then convert it to the list:

```
import numpy as np

first = -(np.arange(10, -11, -1))
```

Notice the negation sign for first.

```
second = np.arange(-10, 11)
```

Convert it to the list as follow or use it as numpy.ndarray type.

```
to_the_list = first.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

#Treversed list in reverse direction

l1=[2,4,3]

for i in range (len(l1)-1,-1,-1):
print (l1[i])

Comment: Output => 3 4 2  Range function Syntax

range(start, stop, step)
Parameter Values
Parameter Description

start Optional. An integer number specifying at which position to start. Default is 0
stop Required. An integer number specifying at which position to stop (not included).
step Optional. An integer number specifying the incrementation. Default is 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).