# Python countdown sequence

Tags: python

I need to write a code that counts down from n to 1
If input is 7, output would be [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

```
def countdown(n):
    L = list(range(n,1))
    while n > 0:
        print(n)
        n = n - 1 
        return L
```

This is what I've tried and its not working. Not even close

Comment: You need to tell it to count down with a negative stride. See the docs for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python range() with negative strides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910090/python-range-with-negative-strides)

Comment: On a side note, you just want to return the range instance. The list conversion and loop are useless.

Comment: Check the docs of [range(start, stop, step)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). Also in an iteration like this you would want the return to be outside the for-or-while-loop, otherwise it will finish on the first iteration.

Comment: Returning the range instance would not result in the correct output, @MisterMiyagi. A list and a range object are two different things.

Comment: @FedericoS Since the question doesn't specify how the result is used, it is hard to tell what is correct. Either way, range instances provide the full sequence interface, which should be more than adequate for a countdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def countdown(n):
    L = list(range(n,0,-1))
    return L
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is inside the `while` loop, which makes it return before the whole loop is finished, furthermore, the `range()` call does not indicate the negative stride.

In any case, the `for` loop would be more appropriate for this case:

```py
def countdown(n):
    result = []
    for x in range(n, 0, -1):
        result.append(x)

    return result
```

An even better approach would be a list comprehension:

```py
def countdown(n):
    return [x for x in range(n, 0, -1)]
```

Finally, the most direct solution is to simply convert the range into a list, skipping any sort of loop in your implementation:

```py
def countdown(n):
    return list(range(n, 0, -1))
```

Note how the variable names are in lower case by convention, to distinguish them from class names and constants (which are respectively TitleCase and CAPS).

Comment: If he actually wanted a list, `list(range(...)) ` is clearer and faster than both your approaches. There is a good chance he does not - range already implements the sequence interface.

Comment: The question very clearly states that the desired shape of the output is a list, not a range object.

Comment: I doubt he knows the difference. The title asks for a "countdown sequence". Either way, suggesting to use loops for a list conversion is bad advice.